# Box-sizing does not affect the padding

Tags: html, css, padding

Hey everyone I am super new to coding and I've made my research and finally come to conclusion that if I don't want the padding or margin to effect the total size I have to use `box-sizing:border-box` but here in the example if I change the padding it affects the total width and size and the container gets bigger? How do I solve this? İ've tried changing the display property but I couldn't make it. I also tried using `box-sizing:border-box` in the .mid_card element itself and still the same. :(

A note: I've used SASS I also tried changing the CSS code too but problem(i think its not a problem its me who doesn't know how to code :() kept being alive!

Thanks in advance.

```css
body {
  font-size: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mid {
  background-color: #f6f9fc;
  margin: 1rem;
  height: 95vh;
}

.mid__card {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 4rem;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: .1em solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 0.2rem 0.4rem 0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.171);
  height: 10rem;
  width: 40rem;
  padding: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&family=Staatliches&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="mid">
  <div class="mid__title">
    <h1 class="mid__title__head">Our Team</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="mid__card">

    <h2 class="mid__card__title">Roger Harry</h2>

    <h3 class="mid__card__subtitle">Founder</h3>

    <p class="mid__card__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum animi magni hic molestias? Et adipisci cum ad doloremque exercitationem corporis error dolorum, voluptatem, dicta tenetur sunt nam explicabo quaerat architecto. Placeat corrupti esse
      debitis, veritatis nihil suscipit voluptates dolorem ab architecto est officiis laboriosam velit, sit dolore fugiat perferendis doloribus totam harum! Autem accusantium placeat fugiat soluta dolorem quidem eaque.
    </p>
    <button class="mid__card__button">LinkedİN</button>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`box-sizing: border-box` *does* force all padding on selected elements to not affect the total size of the element like you mentioned. You are correct. The problem with your code is you were only setting this property on the `body` element on your first line:

```
body {
  font-size: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* this is only affecting the body element */
}
```

I moved that rule outside of the `body` selector into a **universal selector** which selects *all* elements in the document. This allows your element in question `.mid_card` to not grow larger when padding is applied.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* moved this rule outside of body to affect all elements */
}
body {
  font-size: 10px;
}
.mid {
  background-color: #f6f9fc;
  margin: 1rem;
  height: 95vh;
}
.mid__card {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 4rem;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: .1em solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 0.2rem 0.4rem 0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.171);
  height: 15rem; /* increased height to avoid clipping */
  width: 40rem;
  padding: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="mid">
    <div class="mid__title">
      <h1 class="mid__title__head">Our Team</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="mid__card">
      <h2 class="mid__card__title">Roger Harry</h2>
      <h3 class="mid__card__subtitle">Founder</h3>
      <p class="mid__card__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum animi magni hic molestias? Et adipisci cum ad doloremque exercitationem corporis error dolorum, voluptatem, dicta tenetur sunt nam explicabo quaerat architecto. Placeat corrupti esse
        debitis, veritatis nihil suscipit voluptates dolorem ab architecto est officiis laboriosam velit, sit dolore fugiat perferendis doloribus totam harum! Autem accusantium placeat fugiat soluta dolorem quidem eaque.
      </p>
      <button class="mid__card__button">LinkedİN</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

So you can see how this works in action: See the snippet below. The square on the left has default `box-sizing` whereas the square on the right has `box-sizing: border-box` applied. In this animation, as you can see we are increasing the padding of the div. **Notice the div on the right never grows in size as the padding increases**

```css
* {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial;
}
body, div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
div {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  width: 7.5em; height: 7.5em;
  background-color: #09f; color: #ccf;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  animation-name: add-padding;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
p {
  background-color: rgba( 0,0,0,0.125 );
}
@keyframes add-padding {
  100% {
    padding: 2.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>default</p>
</div>

<div style='box-sizing: border-box'>
  <p>box-sizing: border-box</p>
</div>
```

### Edit

**Adding a screen recording below so OP can see the padding size increase in dev tools without affecting the total dimensions of the div in question.**

[image]

Comment: İ should have write it down when i was asking the question at the first place. İ've tried using universal selector but it still grows bigger.

Comment: If you applied the universal selector to your code prior you did not apply it correctly. In the snippets above you can try editing the code and adding as much padding as you like. The div does not grow larger in the code I've provided. **I added an animation to help you visualize what's happening. click `show code snippet`.**

Comment: Thank you so much. But thats not the case i've applied it correctly thats why i was asking a question it makes me crazy. Im still having the same problem. This time if i change the padding the elements inside the card moves out of it instead of getting smaller and going to the middle.

Comment: @berboş To prove to you this code works I'm adding a screen recording of the padding on your div `mid_card` increasing and decreasing. The total dimensions of your div are not being effected. Are you sure you're not not applying this wrong in your code?

Comment: thank you so so much for helping me out!. İ would be super happy if you'd  also tell me why the elements inside the mid__card moves outside of its parent element when we add padding and also why are they first going to middle and then to the bottom right?

Comment: @berboş What's happening in the screen recording in the answer above is our div `.mid_card` has a set height and width with `box-sizing: border-box` applied. So as we add padding the content inside of our div is pushed further and further into the middle of the element. This happens because we told the browser to not expand to the width or height padding is added. So it expands inwards. Inside the element. But also as you can see in the screen recording is this breaks down once the combined padding is greater than the available space inside the div. Increasing padding then does increase dim...

Comment: dimensions because the content needs somewhere to go. We said padding cannot increase our elements dimensions with `box-sizing: border-box` but once padding is greater than available space inside it has no where to go but outward - most developers would normally never give an element this much padding. There's not many great use cases for this and you can usually achieve whatever design you want in much better ways. The content isn't being pushed to the bottom right its being pushed into the center as the whole width expands. If any of this answers your question please accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's the `margin` which is *not*  included in the total width when `box-sizing` is `border-box` - the  `padding` (and `border` width) *is*  always included with that setting. Don't mix these two up.

Comment: *"`border-box` tells the browser to account for any border and padding in the values you specify for an element's width and height. If you set an element's width to 100 pixels, that 100 pixels will include any border or padding added, and the content box will shrink to absorb that extra width. This makes it much easier to size elements."* taken from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing. Padding and border **are** included in total dimensions with `border-box`. OP is asking how to include it in div. So adding `box-sizing: border-box` to div in question is a solution.

Comment: @devsandbox From the question: "if I don't want the padding or margin to effect the total size I have to use box-sizing:border-box" . I already had read your answer and the comments to it from the OP before I wrote, so my answer maybe could also be regarded as a comment, but since the OP writes that adding `box-sizing:border-box` with a universal selector doesn't change the behaviour, I can only suspect that they are changing the margin, hence my answer.